# Apache server not allowing Authorization Header in http request

Tags: apache, http-headers, authorization

I have discovered a strange problem.
I have to send JWT token in the http post request, all this time it was working when I was testing locally running Python web server that accepts post request but now that when I have uploaded my code to server I discovered that Authorization Header is not getting passed.

So earlier I thought it is the length of jwt  but to my surprise if I remove last letter n from Authorization the header gets passed to server.

Is it the Apache server blocking Authorization Header?  Because locally it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out in  tag of website.conf file

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```